# Functions are not valid as react child Error while using Navigate in react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am getting the error ("Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.") when I am trying to use condition which includes Navigate to "/path" (look at the statement in the code).

```
return (
  <>
    <Router>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand to="/">MoviesReviews</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Link to="/picks">Picks</Link>
            <Link to="/critics">Critics</Link>
          </Nav>
          <Form className="d-flex">
            <FormControl
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search"
              className="me-2"
              aria-label="Search"
              id = "SearchBox"
            />
            {redirect === true? (() => (<Navigate to = "/search"/>)) : null}
            <Button variant="outline-success" onClick = {() => pressSearch()}>Search</Button>
          </Form>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
        <Routes>
          <Route path = "/" element = {<Reviews/>}/>
          <Route exact path = "/picks" element = {<Reviews/>}/> 
          <Route exact path = "/critics" element = {<Critics/>}/>
          <Route exact path = "/search" element = {<SearchReviews search = {searchString}/>}/>
        </Routes>
    </Router>
  </>
);
```

If you look at the Route exact path for "/search", you see that I am actually returning a `<Component/>`. I am pretty sure the problem is in the line which contains the condition (`{redirect === true? (() => (<Navigate to = "/search"/>)) : null}`).

Comment: Yeah, that line is the problem. Did you mean to do `{redirect === true ? <Navigate to="/search"/> : null}`?

Comment: No, this does not fix the problem. I had tried however I get this error: Maximum update depth exceeded. It goes to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are not valid JSX, they can't be rendered.

If you are conditionally rendering React components there are a couple syntaxes you can use, neither involves using a function. It's considered bad practice to compare boolean variables against true/false, just use the variable's value for the condition. If you just need to test the truthy/falsey-ness of a value then use `!!` to coerce it to a strict boolean value.

- Using a ternary: `condition ? <Component1 /> : null`

  ```
  {redirect ? <Navigate to="/search" replace /> : null}
  ```

  This is useful if you need to conditionally render one of two different components, or to return null as a component result.
- Using logical AND (`&&`): `condition && <Component1 />`

  ```
  {redirect && <Navigate to="/search" replace />}
  ```

  This is useful if you only need to conditionally render a single component.

If you are conditionally rendering the entire component render result then you should use the first in order to return null as valid JSX.

### Suggestion

It would be better to issue an imperative redirect instead of setting any `redirect` state. This has the benefit of not requiring an additional React render cycle to effect the change.

In order for this component to use any `react-router-dom` hooks, the `Router` will need to be moved higher in the ReactTree, i.e. to the parent component or higher of this component.

Example:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const Component = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  // logic to replace setting any `redirect` state
  if (<condition to redirect>) {
    navigate("/search", { replace: true });
  }

  ...

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand to="/">MoviesReviews</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Link to="/picks">Picks</Link>
            <Link to="/critics">Critics</Link>
          </Nav>
          <Form className="d-flex">
            <FormControl
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search"
              className="me-2"
              aria-label="Search"
              id = "SearchBox"
            />
            <Button
              variant="outline-success"
              onClick={pressSearch}
            >
              Search
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Reviews />} />
          <Route path="/picks" element={<Reviews />} /> 
          <Route path="/critics" element={<Critics />} />
          <Route path="/search" element={<SearchReviews search={searchString} />} />
        </Routes>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi Drew, Thanks for the answer. However, I want to notify as per your suggestion, We cannot use useNavigation outside return function if we have <Router> inside the return function. To solve this, I created a separate js file in which I put all the above code which was inside <Router>...</Router>.

Comment: @AryanArya Yes, sorry, I missed that. Using any `react-router` hooks assumes a router is being rendered somewhere higher up in the ReactTree than the component using the hook.

Answer (score 1):

`{redirect === true? (() => (<Navigate to = "/search"/>)) : null}` with the above statement you :

1. in `false` case you are returning null.
2. in `true` case you are trying to render a function.

```
() => (<Navigate to = "/search"/>)
```

Hence it is not valid as a react child.

You have to do : `{redirect === true ? <Navigate to="/search"/> : null}` as mentioned in comments.